# mypy error when reshaping an array with a list of tuples

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python module that looks as following:

```
import numpy as np

def test(order: str = 'C') -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((1,2), order = order)
```

evaluating this with mypy returns the error and notes

```
error: No overload variant of "reshape" of "_ArrayOrScalarCommon" matches argument types "Tuple[int, int]", "str"
note: Possible overload variants:
note:     def reshape(self, Sequence[int], *, order: Union[Literal['A'], Literal['C'], Literal['F'], None] = ...) -> ndarray
note:     def reshape(self, *shape: int, order: Union[Literal['A'], Literal['C'], Literal['F'], None] = ...) -> ndarray
```

Substituting the section order = order in the function call with order = 'C' stops this error from occuring. Why is it a problem for mypy if I choose to pass this parameter as a function argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test(order: str = 'C')` only sets the default value of parameter `C`
but you can still call it with any `str`.  For instance `test('X')` is
correctly typed.  But this causes `test` to call `reshape` with
`order='X'` which is wrong and this is why mypy complains and this is
a good thing.

So the problem lies in the type definition of `order`.  You can change
it match the `reshape` signature, and mypy is happy with it:

```py
import typing as tp
import numpy as np

def test(order: tp.Optional[tp.Literal['A', 'C', 'F']] = 'C') -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((1,2), order = order)

test('C')  # ok
test('X')  # mypy error
```

Comment: I see. Is there also an equivalent to literal for numbers, e.g. if I want to only allow a specified set of ints as a function argument

Comment: @hhhh `Literal` also works for integers. For instance, this is valid: `x: tp.Literal[1, 2, 3] = 2` and this will raise an error: `x: tp.Literal[1, 2, 3] = 4`.